# Inserting a new column in InDesign changes the paragraph style by adding a + to the name. Why?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

When I add a new column to a table in InDesign CS6 and I click into a new created cell it has a `+` in the style name. When I hover over the style it shows: *"Overrides(alt+click to clear): (align: flush left)"*.

This means that the new cell is aligned left instead of maintaining the original style, which is center aligned. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

thanks (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say why for sure, smells like a bug, but there is a way to stop it.

Just tested it out (CS6) and it does seem to always add a left-align override to paragraph styles in new columns. **But**, if you give your table cells a **cell style that is set to use your centre-aligned paragraph style**, then in new columns with that cell style, the paragraph style's alignment is respected and not overridden.

So, I imagine the default cell style includes something (bug?) that applies a left-aligned override. When there's a cell style that sets a paragraph style, it doesn't use that default and so doesn't apply the override.

Comment: Well I don't manually apply the cell style to the cell. I apply the table style to the table and it automatically add the styles to cells; header, body-normal and body-left cells.

Comment: Is it the cell style that is set to apply the paragraph style? Or is the paragraph style applied manually?

Comment: cell style defined the paragraph style;